# Solution Upgrade, Activating feature as well

Tags: sharepoint-server, solution-deployment

I have deployed a solution on my test server with 1 features that creates an AppConfig list and add 3 list items, I used visual studio to create list items.

```
<Data>
        <Rows>
            <Row>
                <Field Name="Title">UmbracoSiteUrl</Field>
                <Field Name="Value">http://localhost:55942/</Field>
            </Row>
            <Row>
                <Field Name="Title">UmbracoServiceKey</Field>
                <Field Name="Value">sharepoint</Field>
            </Row>
            <Row>
                <Field Name="Title">UmbracoServiceValue</Field>
                <Field Name="Value">LetMeInSoICanWork</Field>
            </Row>
        </Rows>
    </Data>
```

I made a few code related changes in a timer job and is now going to upgrade solution. When I call solution upgrade it successfully update the dll but also added 3 more entries in the list.

Is this behavior by design or am I missing something?

Comment: it addes entries to which list?

Comment: AppConfig list, my custom list.

Answer (score 0):

when do you create the list items? I guess you get 3 more items because you create them at every deployment.